# Can I find an analytic self map of the unit disc satisfying lower conditions?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to find an analytic self map  $\phi$ of the unit disc $\mathbb{D}$, which satisfies
$$\phi\neq\mathrm{id};\; \mbox{and}$$ $$\mathrm{Closure\;of\;}\phi(\mathbb{D})\cap\partial\mathbb{D}\neq\emptyset; \;\mbox{and}$$
$$\lim\limits_{|\phi(z)|\rightarrow1}\frac{(1-|z|^2)(|\phi(z)-z|)}{(1-|\phi（z)|^2)(1-\max\{{|z|,|\phi(z)|}\})^2}|\phi'(z)|=0.$$

Does such $\phi$ exists? If it does, how to construct an example?